# list names and data form registry key in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, registry, regedit

I want to list this in my program using vb.net from registry key (Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run)
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SAk8.jpg
the goal is to get this data from  here to a listview in m program
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ews7I.jpg
thanks  alot

Edit 
I found this project  but
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3495/Registry-List-Control
it  give me  this  result
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGUfZ.jpg
and the registry  info is
https://imgur.com/Z31T3XF
why ?

Comment: Your question is missing the piece of code that's failing.

Answer (score 0):

ok  it was very easy hahahaha sorry  Idon't know that
the sulation  is 
export  the  key by this cmd  command 
reg.exe export HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run   C:\Users\Kasp3r\Desktop/RunonStartup.txt
and finally worked